# How to Inherit multiple classes in python dynamically

Tags: python, inheritance, reflection, multiple-inheritance

Can any one help me to inherit multiple classes in python.

Let say I have three classes in three different modules.

a.py :

```
class A():
   def __init__(self):
      pass

   def fruit(self):
     print "Apple is a fruit"
```

b.py :

```
class B():
    def __init__(self):
       pass

    def vegetable(self):
       print "Potato is a vegetable"
```

c.py :

```
class C():
  def __init__(self):
      pass

  def vehicle(self):
     print "Car is a vehicle"
```

I just want to configure all these class names in a file like , a.A , b.B and c.C. then read the configuration file and load the configured modules  and inherit those modules( Multiple Inheritance ).

utility.py

```
Read configuration and get the modules.

class Utility(INHERIT_CONFIGURED_MODULES):
    def __init__(self):
       pass

obj = Utility()
obj.fruit()
obj.vegetable()
obj.vehicle()
```

Now ,If I create one more module and configure that in my configuration file,then I should access its methods using the objected created for Utility class.

Hope its clear.Please guide me to achieve this.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? There's probably a much cleaner way to implement it.

Comment: @Philiip. thanks for the mention. I solved the problem.               modules = ['a.A','b.B','c.C']

collect = []

for module in modules:
    (mod,cls) = module.split('.')
    imp=__import__(mod,globals(), locals(),[cls],-1)
    collect.append(getattr(imp,cls))

class Utility():
    def __init__(self):
        pass

obj=Utility()
Utility.__bases__ = (tuple(collect))
obj.vehicle()
obj.fruit()